# Font not supported in the website and the font is not in GoogleAPI

Tags: html, css

My website is not showing my fonts...
CSS Code is as follows...

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'IconicStroke';
    src: url("fonts/iconic/iconic_stroke.eot");
    src: local('IconicStroke'),
       url("fonts/iconic/iconic_stroke.svg#iconic") format('svg'),
       url("fonts/iconic/iconic_stroke.otf") format('opentype');
}
.iconic {
    color:inherit;
    font-family: "IconicStroke";
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please help...
It is showing in my machine but its not showing after uploading in the space....

Comment: are you sure you have the right path for your font? or is your font available to the browser you're testing?

Comment: Check your developer console.

Comment: fonts are in the right path as it showing in my machine... but when uploaded its not shoiwng the fonts.

Comment: did you uploaded the files to server in the same path?

Comment: Yes, its uploaded with the same path....

Comment: Can you give us url of your site?

Comment: http://rgvnnemfl.com

Comment: `<link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` First of all, this file doesn't even exist.

Comment: it is there in the httpdocs folder in the server....

Answer (score 2):

There is no `http://rgvnnemfl.com/iconic.css`, which I'm guessing is where you have the above code. I think your link to the iconic.css is wrong.

Comment: it is there in the **httpdosc** folder

Answer (score 1):

If your css in css folder, then your fonts path may be

```
../fonts/iconic/iconic_stroke.eot
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
font-family: "IconicStroke"; src: url('../fonts/iconic/iconic_stroke.eot'); 
} 

.iconic {
font-family: "IconicStroke", sans-serif;
}
```

This should work just fine.